# Where to install Ionic with a Laravel backend?

Tags: angularjs, laravel, ionic-framework

I have an existing webapp built on Laravel. I am moving to an Ionic build to create the native version. 
How would you suggest I separate my views, and how do I call the routes? Has anyone any example.

Here is what I am about to do: 
1.  move all my views to the public folder
2.  install Ionic in the public folder,
3. Using UI-route & Angular make $http calls to the backend.

Thanks for your input :-)

Comment: Your Laravel webapp should be.converted into a JSON API so your Ionic app could make HTTP-calls to it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't simply do that.

If you have a "classic" Laravel app with blade templates, what you need to do is to expose an `API` from it.

Then you create an ionic app in a different directory (they are not related, so you don't have to mix them). You just need to develop your ionic app like any other ionic app. Then in your factories where you do the request to your `API`, you do something like:

```
$http.get('https://example.com/api/foo')
```

Where `example.com` is the domain of your Laravel application (You are going to need to activate CORS in it).

You just can't simply create an ionic app inside laravel, because that application will be built into an .apk to be installed on the phone and you can't add Laravel inside the package.

So the **TL;DR** is having your normal Laravel app where it lives, add it some public API so your ionic app can access it and then build an Ionic app from zero that will use that API.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on you, but I prefer to keep the ionic project nested in /public, since I want a single-project app, the sources are clearly separated by being or not in the subfolder, but it helps your productivity, benefits are:

- **Single source control**: Single source set for source version control (GIT, SVN, ...), so when I work I can do a single pull/checkout and push/checkin
- **Single app to deploy**: Single domain, no cross-domain problems, single deploy via FTP is available, any standard php server can handle it with a single and standard account to handle
- **Coherent project without interdipendencies**: I do not want to split logic dependencies of the same model between many projects, when I change something in backend or frontend that involve the other side, I want to have in the same project all the sources to update. It make not sense to have to go to a different project to adjust compatibility, it would be uselessy messy